# How to set RDS security layer in Windows Server 2008 R2 via PowerShell

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, tls, rds

I'm looking for a way to set security layer setting in Windows Server 2008 R2 RDS via PowerShell (other ways to do in programmatically will do also but PowerShell is preferable). Via GUI it can be set through RDP-Tcp properties on General tab (SSL, Negotiata, RDS Security layers are available options), any advice on hot to change this via PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the RDS: PowerShell Provider, you can do the following --

```
Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices
Set-Location RDS:\RDSConfiguration\Connections\RDP-Tcp\SecuritySettings
# Choose One of the following 
Set-Item .\SecurityLayer 0 # Sets it to RDP Security Layer
Set-Item .\SecurityLayer 1 # Sets it to Negotiate
Set-Item .\SecurityLayer 2 # Sets it to SSL (TLS 1.0)
```

You can also find the setting under `Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative templates -> Windows Components -> Terminal Services -> Terminal Server -> Security` and set it using Group Policy.